# Tomcat internet explorer kerberos authentication 401 un authorized

Tags: active-directory, tomcat7, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, kerberos

We configured tomcat to work with windows authentication using kerberos (we want SSO).
From a different client machine via Internet Explorer we send HTTP Get, the browser returns 401 and the header say Negotiate.
We configured internet explorer to use Integrated security and added the tomcat site address as local intranet.

On the tomcat logs i see:

```
Loaded from Java config
>>> KdcAccessibility: reset
>>> KrbCreds found the default ticket granting ticket in credential cache.
>>> Obtained TGT from LSA: Credentials:
  client=wfuser@MY.DOM
  server=krbtgt/MY.DOM@MY.DOM
  authTime=20160111063609Z
  startTime=20160111063609Z
  endTime=20160111163609Z
  renewTill=null
  flags=INITIAL;PRE-AUTHENT
  EType (skey)=17
  (tkt key)=18
  Search Subject for SPNEGO ACCEPT cred (<<DEF>>, sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoCredElement)
Search Subject for Kerberos V5 ACCEPT cred (<<DEF>>, sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential)
Found ticket for wfuser@MY.DOM to go to krbtgt/NIA.DOM@MY.DOM expiring on Mon Jan 11 18:36:09 IST 2016
```

What could be the issue ? Is this an internet explorer issue ? or maybe tomcat issue ?

Comment: Have you checked with HTTP trace (like liveHTTPHeaders plugin) that Browser sends back the 'Authorization' request header.

The 'TGT' , seen in the logs is used by Tomcat itself ... see your other post

Comment: Could you please show us your login.conf file/settings? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html

Comment: Something does not feel right based on your output. Tomcat has either to use a keytab for the machine account or access the credential cache of the machine account if running on Windows. None happens in your log files. Unless you show the exception and more log output, it will be impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The client and Tomcat server appear to be in different Kerberos realms (I will assume controlled by Active Directory due to the way you tagged your post).  That is, the Active Directory domain client is in MY.DOM and but the Tomcat server in NIA.DOM.  For this to work as you're expecting, they'll need to be in the same AD domain/Kerberos realm.  According to the log snippet, the client and KDC show in the same realm - MY.DOM - according to this:

```
>>> Obtained TGT from LSA: Credentials:
  client=wfuser@MY.DOM
  server=krbtgt/MY.DOM@MY.DOM
```

But the Tomcat server must not be, because it seems to be asking the client for a referral ticket from a Kerberos realm named NIA.DOM.

```
Found ticket for wfuser@MY.DOM to go to krbtgt/NIA.DOM@MY.DOM expiring on Mon Jan 11 18:36:09 IST 2016
```

Examine the AD Trust relationship between MY.DOM and NIA.DOM and make sure it is two-way and not broken.